# Can't connect to YouTube from specific network

Tags: networking, internet-connection, youtube

Using my current network, I am unable to connect to http://www.youtube.com/.

It doesn't matter what browser I use or if I use a cli-command (`wget`, `curl`).

Error in Google Chrome:

```
Oops! Google Chrome could not connect to www.youtube.com
```

Error using curl:

```
curl: (7) couldn't connect to host
```

If I use `nslookup` to get the IP-address of YouTube, I get `173.194.32.32`.

If I go to `http://173.194.32.32/` in my browser it can connect, but as Google is probably checking the `Host` HTTP-header, it shows Google's frontpage instead.

There is no blocked websites on the router and other devices on the network seems to work.
My computer only has this problem on this specific network.

I am using Mac OS X 10.8.2 on a MacBook (mid 2009).

Comment: Try flushing and renewing the DNS, But it might be a  DNS malware issue, so try a malware remover.

Comment: @Lamb, wouldn't that effect all networks? It only happens on this network and has happened last time I used this network too.

Comment: this is a DNS renewal error, reset the time on your clock on your computer and that should work. How long has this been going on?

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this error appear for various reasons, there's usually 2 ways this is fixed, it's something on the sites end, I.E. updating something and within 24 hours the problem could be resolved, or 2 it's a problem on your end, usually the router, I know it sounds simple but try simply pulling the power cord on your router/modem for 30 seconds and trying again.

Answer (score 0):

Flushing the DNS fixed the problem for me.

**Edit:** This is only a temporary fix, as when I disconnect from the network and later re-connect it happens again.